# Rails Gem "Axlsx" - Rename Workbook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, axlsx

My workbook always named like my template "invoices_generate.xlsx".
How can i rename this File ?

Template "invoices_generate.xlsx.axlsx" :

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook

    wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Beleg") do |sheet|  

    .
    .
    .

    sheet.column_widths 2 , 11, 11, 11, 11, 23, 3

    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the axlsx_rails gem added as well? If so:

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(name: "Beleg") do |sheet|
  sheet.column_widths 2 , 11, 11, 11, 11, 23, 3
end
```

See https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails#template for more details and if that doesn't work try setting the filename from the controller action rendering the xlsx template as described here: https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails#file-name

Comment: Using name under `add_worksheet` only names the sheet. So yes, it will have to be done in the controller with a `render :xlsx` statement. Without this, there will be no filename http header, and the browser will guess a name based on the URL.

Comment: Actually this doesn't resolve the original question because this answer changes the name of the worksheet, not the file

Answer (score 0):

For future references: In the controller, on the function where generate the workbook

```
def index
  @users =  User.all

  render xlsx: 'export', filename: 'my_new_filename.xlsx' //Render with export and naming the file
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xlsx
  end
end
```